# Spring Boot - ApplicationContext Null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have combined the following two projects:

https://github.com/jpenninkhof/odata-boilerplate
and
https://github.com/isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA

I have them working separatedly but when I combine them in the same project the call to http://localhost:9004/odata.svc doesn't work. The attribute attribute applicationContext is null. Actually in the tab Expresions is null but on the tooltip has still the right value

[image: Value of applicationContext]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.accolite.pru.health</groupId>
    <artifactId>AuthApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AuthApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url>https://github.com/isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>


        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Aman Garg</name>
            <email>amangargcse@outlook.com</email>
            <timezone>5</timezone>
            <id>isopropylcyanide</id>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA.git
        </developerConnection>
        <connection>scm:git@github.com:isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA.git</connection>
        <url>https://github.com/isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA/tree/master</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <issueManagement>
        <system>GitHub Issues</system>
        <url>https://github.com/isopropylcyanide/Jwt-Spring-Security-JPA/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>

    <properties>
        <!--Build -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <!--Build -->
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.28</freemarker.version>

        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <expiring.map.version>0.5.9</expiring.map.version>

        <!--Sonar / Code Coverage -->
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <surefire.version>2.19.1</surefire.version>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.2</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/*Configuration.java,**/*Exception.java,**/conf/**/*,**/model/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cxf.version>3.3.6</cxf.version>
        <olingo.version>2.0.11</olingo.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.14.FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Java 8 Date/Time Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <!--Swagger UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Swagger 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Expiring Map -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>expiringmap</artifactId>
            <version>${expiring.map.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-api-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo.version}</version>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--Jacoco Code Coverage Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- pre-unit-test execution helps setting up some maven property, which 
                        will be used later by JaCoCo -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>coverage-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <destFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                            <!-- passing property which will contains settings for JaCoCo agent. 
                                If not specified, then "argLine" would be used for "jar" packaging -->
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>download-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

AuthAppApplication.java

```
package com.accolite.pru.health.AuthApp;


@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        AuthAppApplication.class,
        Jsr310JpaConverters.class
})
public class AuthAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

StringContextUtil.java

```
package com.accolite.pru.health.AuthApp.utils;

@Component
public class SpringContextsUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringContextsUtil.class);
    
    
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public SpringContextsUtil() {
        logger.debug("Loading SpringContextsUtil");
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        logger.debug("Inject ApplicationContext: {} into SpringContextsUtil", applicationContext);
        SpringContextsUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String name) throws BeansException {
        return applicationContext.getBean(name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static Object getBean(String name, Class requiredType) throws BeansException {
        return applicationContext.getBean(name, requiredType);
    }

    public static boolean containsBean(String name) {
        return applicationContext.containsBean(name);
    }

    public static boolean isSingleton(String name) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {
        return applicationContext.isSingleton(name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static Class getType(String name) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {
        return applicationContext.getType(name);
    }

    public static String[] getAliases(String name) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {
        return applicationContext.getAliases(name);
    }


}
```

CxfServletRegister.java

```
@Configuration
public class CxfServletRegister {
    
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet> getODataServletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet> odataServletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet>(new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet(), "/odata.svc/*");
        Map<String, String> initParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParameters.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", "org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.app.ODataApplication");
        initParameters.put("org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory", "com.accolite.pru.health.AuthApp.utils.JPAServiceFactory");
        odataServletRegistrationBean.setInitParameters(initParameters);
        return odataServletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is as in the original projects,

Comment: Why is there an @Autowired annotation on your screenshot for the field ```private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;```, but in the code snippet ```SpringContextsUtil``` I don't see this annotation?

Comment: Hi saver, good point :) I was trying with and without Autowired. It seems the screenshot was taken after I tried with Autowired.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following dependency was interfering. I removed it and now it works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```